# Sharepoint 2010 workflow email error "Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly"

Tags: email, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, smtp

I have configured my sharepoint server for outgoing email. I used this tutorial

https://manojviduranga.wordpress.com/tag/configure-sharepoint-outgoing-email-step-by-step/

also tried this one:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288949(v=office.14).aspx#section5

to test if it's working, I created a simple list workflow to send email everytime a new item is created. when I create a new item in the list, the workflow progress is "Complete" but the email is not sent and there's a workflow error "The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly."

I check all possible solutions I could find. checked the anti-virus, tried adding a pause in the workflow, restarted server and iis. I kept getting the same workflow error.
is there any other solution that could fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to be certain that Sharepoint can send emails. To do that just go to your list and in the top menu choose List and then "Alert me". Now set to receive new alerts on newly created items.

Now create new item and check if you received email. If not - your sharepoint or SMTP server is misconfigured.

You can diagnose your SMTP server by opening telnet client (start->run->cmd-> type "telnet"). 
in telnet client write:

```
open yoursmtpserveraddress:25
helo test
mail from:anyone@yourdomain.com
rcpt to:your_email@yourdomain.com
data
.
```

If this will succeed without errors, then your SMTP server is working. Then you should check Sharepoint configuration. Otherwise reconfigure your smtp server and/or firewall.